# Laravel Request showing error, _POST showing the variables

Tags: post, request, laravel-5

I have `route.php` like below :

```
Route::get('/edit/{num}', [
        'as' => 'department.edit',
        'middleware' => ['admin'],
        'uses' => 'DepartmentsController@edit'
    ]);

    Route::post('/update/{num}', [
        'as' => 'department.update',
        'middleware' => ['admin'],
        'uses' => 'DepartmentsController@update'
    ]);
```

And `edit.blade.php` as below :

```
{!! Form::model($department, array('route' => ['department.update', Crypt::encrypt($department->id)], 'id' => 'department_update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal row-border')) !!}
                @include('admin.departments._form')
                {!! Form::label('', '', array('class' => 'col-md-2 control-label')) !!}
                {!! Form:: submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
            {!!form::close()!!}
```

And the `DepartmentsController.php` `update()` as :

```
public function update($id, Request $request) { 
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id); 
        dd($_POST);
}
```

The above showing the POST variables :

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "UI6tBMuJlwmGZuaeB9ilJq6v0wUMOgKRlEY4eY0I"
  "name" => "Material Management"
  "department_code" => "MMD"
]
```

But if I try to output `dd($request)`, it throws error

> ReflectionException in AbstractCloner.php line 245: Class 1 does not
>   exist

Whats wrong ? Where I have made the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, move your `$request` to 1st params.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) { 
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id); 
        dd($request->all()); 
        dd($_POST);
}
```

Comment: $request->all() did the thing :)

Comment: Yes, now you can get your desire form value by this `$request->get('name')` .....